# Android Studio Screen Capture

Tags: android

I would like to take screen shot of my app and I would like to share that screen shot  in mail,blue tooth,social medias etc.. I don't know how to perform screen shot and to share it how it can be done?

Comment: wich emulator r u using?

Comment: running in  lollipop device

Comment: so u need to screen capture through adb?

Comment: if you r using a mobile device as emulator u can take screenshot using the inbuild function fo the device... it is available in most of the devices... if you r using any other emulator, u might need to do screen capture thru adb... if u r using a mobile device give me its brand and model number...

Comment: I to knew that.I would like to include the screen shot option in my app for example am having a button like screen shot while clicking the screen shot button it should be attached to our mail.

Comment: If this feature is about your app, *Android Studio*, which is included in the title, has no relation.

Comment: Check out : http://www.truiton.com/2013/03/android-take-screenshot-programmatically-and-send-email/

Answer (score 1):

1.Start the app in Debug Mode.
2.click Android to open the Android DDMS tool window.
3. Click Screen Capture on the left side of the Android DDMS tool window.
4. Optional: To add a device frame around your screenshot, enable the Frame  and 
take the screenshot option.
 and Save It

You can even try **printscreen** or s**nipping tool** in windows.. and edit the view as 
you want

The newly manufactures Android smartphones are already receiving very easy methods to take screenshot on them. So, you do not require any third party application or software for this purpose rather you will have to use the easy and reliable method to do so, which is also the time saving feature in this time-valued world.

So, I will share the easy method to take screenshot on Samsung Galaxy trend, 
**Method – Take Screenshot using Hardware Combination Method**
STEP 1 – You will notice Power Key on the right side of the phone and Volume keys on the left hand side.

STEP 2 – Now press and hold the two keys for about 2 seconds.

Your screenshot will be taken and stored in the phone’s memory.

Comment: i like to include the screenshot  option in my app itself

Comment: press the power key and the volume keys at the same time for about two seconds. these is how I take screen shots......

Comment: that is normal way.I would like to include it as a button in my app while clicking the button it should take screen shot and it should be attached in my mail its my idea if you know the way to do it means tell me

Answer (score 1):

to include screenshot function your app, you need to grand superuser permission... In other words, third party apps can only take screenshot on rooted device, oru your app should be installed as a system app...

Comment: am having all those permission to perform changes in my app kindly tell me the way to do it